# IE8 rendering of local-files is wrong

Tags: file, internet-explorer, rendering, opacity

It appears that IE8 is not rendering properly a local file:

Consider this simple webpage: http://sayang.free.fr/ie8render.html (html code below) extracted from a w3c tutorial on opacity.

Save it locally and display it again: the local file has no opacity!

That's very annoying, especially when one wants to design complex pages on prototypes placed in local files.

Do you have a solution to that ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IE8 Local File</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />

    <style type="text/css">
    div.background
      {
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
      background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg) repeat;
      border: 2px solid black;
      }
    div.transbox
      {
      width: 400px;
      height: 180px;
      margin: 30px 50px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid black;
      /* for IE */
      filter:alpha(opacity=60);
      /* CSS3 standard */
      opacity:0.6;
      }
    div.transbox p
      {
      margin: 30px 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #000000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Save this file locally and open it to see the difference</h2>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox">
        <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box. This is some text that is placed in the transparent box. This is some text that is placed in the transparent box. This is some text that is placed in the transparent box. This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works now: 2 years after, Microsoft must have improved local documents viewing.
It now prompts for executing javascript and actually executes it as if the page was remote.

Many thanks to all of you who have spent some time to reply.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this just before the `<html>` (or between `<!DOCTYPE...>` and `<html>`):

```
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.example.com/ -->
```

If that's there, Internet Explorer acts as if it has fetched the page from a remote web server instead of loaded it directly off disk.

The URL can be pretty much whatever you want, but the number in parentheses must be the length of the URL.

I can't guarantee it will work, but give it a try if you're still interested in this old question :)

Comment: Interesting. Does that help? And if it does: *why?*

Comment: Well, it definitely makes a difference.  When Internet Explorer saves a page (via File|Save) it adds a comment like that.  I suspect it's a usability thing.  Files on your local machine would normally fall into a different security zone, but that would confuse users who saved a page and then later tried to open it locally only to find it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your code works in IE7 you can force IE8 browsers to use IE7 standards by including the following tag inside `<head>`

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this below URL will help you to solve your issue..

http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css3/opacity-transparency.html

Comment: Thank you but it's not a matter of how to implement transparency, but rather how to make it work on a local file.